# Positioning meteor loginButtons modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, modal-dialog

I have the following code in meteor.

myNavbar.html

```
<template name = "myNavbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid" id = "Nav-Content">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div id= "loginNavElm">{{> loginButtons}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

myNavBar.css

```
#Nav-Content{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#loginNavElm{
    padding-top: 1vw; 
}
```

and my layout.html

```
<template name="layout">
  <body>
    {{> myNavbar}}
    <div class="container">
      {{> yield }}
    </div>
  </body>
</template>
```

While I have the effect of putting the login button in the top right where I want it, the modal that pops up justifies itself on the left edge with the login button and because the popup is wider than the button half of it ends up off the right edge of the screen. I was wondering if there was a quick fix here that would have the modal appear at the right edge of the screen instead of over the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the everything else posted this template stands alone to do what needs to happen...

```
<template name = "myNavbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid" id = "Nav-Content">
        <div class="navbar-left" id = "Nav-Title">
            <p id = "pageTitleNavElm">Common</p>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-right">
          <div id= "loginNavElm">{{> loginButtons}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```